# I want stop the script if the subtraction is different to 0

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I have a script to do research in my photo archive.
Beacause I've some files named with a merceological name before.

Since I want to avoid the problem that misspellings cause results to be lost. so I thought about this system.

Eg names files:

```
(Travel and Tourism) – titlea.jpg
(Travel and Tourism) – titleb.jpg
(Drinks) – titlea.jpg
```

I did this idea, 
two researches, one precise with the exact name and the other extremely inaccurate with a few letters (consonants) that it is not possible for them to be missing (unless one does not type drunk). And that obviously are not all present together in other names.
If the subtraction is zero it means that the two results are the same and therefore without errors:

```
    myfindTravelandTourism=$(find /PATH/ -type f -iname '*(Travel and Tourism)*' | wc -l)

    StringVerifyTravelandTourism=$(find /PATH/ | cut -f1 -d '–' | grep
     -i -F 'T' | grep -i -F 'R' | grep -i -F 'V' | wc -l)

    if [ "${myfindTravelandTourism-StringVerifyTravelandTourism}" ≠ "0" ] ; then

    echo "WARNING THE SCRIPT HAS DETECTED AN ORTOGRAPHICAL ERROR IN THE VIAGGI E TURISMO SECTOR!"

    if [ {StringVerifyTravelandTourism} -ne ≠ "$0" ]; then

    exit

    fi

    fi
```

But the error code bash:

```
[: ≠: integer expression expected.
```

I'm a beginner. This is my first conditional statement in bash

Comment: Where are you learning shell scripting? `≠` is not a valid operator; `!=` is the correct operator to use.

Answer (score 0):

This `≠` is not an operator as a result it throws the error.

Also, to check for strings, you should use `!=` instead of `-ne`. For example,

`n1 -ne n2`     To check whether **numbers** are algebraically equal or not.

`s1 != s2`      To check whether **strings** are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet:

```
if [[ $(( myfindTravelandTourism - StringVerifyTravelandTourism)) != 0 ]]; then
    echo "not equal 0"
fi
```